# How do I solve this limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x-\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}\right)$?

Tags: limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find the limit of $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x-\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}\right)$$
I did rooting like this:
$$\frac{\left(x-\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}\right)*\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}\right)}{x+\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}} = \frac{x^2-\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}{x+\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}}$$
but I got stuck. How can I continue from here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the numerator over a common denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the terms in the numerator over the common denominator one obtains:
$$\begin{align}\frac{x^2-\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}{x+\sqrt{\frac{4x^3+3x^2}{4x-3}}}&=\frac{-6x^2}{(4x-3)x\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{4x+3}{4x-3}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{-6}{(4-\frac3{x})\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{4x+3}{4x-3}}\right)}.
\end{align}$$

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Not really. I can see that i can simplify with x. But after that if I replace x with infinity i get critical limits. And if I divide by x, I get 0 as a denominator.

Comment: @WAT Can you take it now after I divided both numerator and denominator by $x^2$?

Comment: Sorry but still no. I don't see how could I get to somewhere wher the limit wouldn't be $\infty$ or 0. Do I multiply it with the conjugate? $$\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{4x+3}{4x-3}}}{1-\sqrt{\frac{4x+3}{4x-3}}}$$

Comment: @WAT What happens if your substitute $x=\infty$ into the denominator? For me it turns into $8$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now. Thank you.